# How can I display "hello world" in an .aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `Default.aspx` and a seperate code file:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       public string hello = "hello world"
   }
}
```

I would like to display this in my Default page i have tried to use <%=hello%> but does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have posted invalid code. This will not compile, let alone let you display anything on the page.

Comment: Also,the "simplest thing" would be to create a new project and then press "F5".

Comment: And "simplest thing" can mean many things, depending on _what exactly_ you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ledge, please format your code and read it through before posting.  Makes it a lot easier for everyone else to read.  Also, as per S.Overflow general guidelines, extraneous niceties (like "Thanks" and "I'm dumb/slow") are unneeded

Comment: Also, +1 for saying what you tried and exactly what you want to happen.  Formatting is learned, but please do put some effort into it.

Comment: Giving you a point for trying as well.  Welcome to ASPX.

Comment: @Christopher Pfohl comments noted thanks

Comment: @Oded apologies fro bad question thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string hello = "hello world";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: With this solution, on your asp/html page you can then reference the public variable `hello` with `<%=hello%>`. I would go with this solution over the response.write() if you want more elements on your page than just "hello world", if you don't then the response.write should suffice.

Answer (score 4):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   string hello = "i need more practice";
   Response.Write(hello);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

also try out

aspx page

```
<%= this.hello%>
```

.cs codebehind file

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string hello = "hello world";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

---

just write this will do the task

```
Response.Write("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code won't compile the way it is.  Try this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string Hello { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hello = "hello world";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a label instead. You will be able to format the output easily

```
 in your .aspx
 <body>
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="HelloLabel"></asp:Label>
 </body>

//code behind
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string hello = "i need more practice";
  HelloLabel.Text = "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually write this to the markup. 
You can do this by creating a label(or literal):
`<asp:Label ID="helloLabel" runat="server" Text = "<%#HelloWorld()%> ></asp:Label>`
Then you will need a function called HelloWorld which returns a string

```
private string HelloWorld()
{
    string hello = "Hello World";
    return hello;
}
```

or you could set the label text directly from a function.

`helloLabel.Text = "Hello World";`